# Is there a way to add a string at the end of a dot without manually typing it?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I want to make an **OreBase** class so that i don't make a new class for every new ore because they should pretty much do the exact same thing: 1. exist, 2. drop the appropriate item that is named before the underscore of the ore name *(ruby_ore -> ruby)*. To return a ruby for a ruby_ore i need to return **ModItems.RUBY**, i can get the string *"RUBY"* from *"ruby_ore"*, but i don't know how to properly add it after *"ModItems."*. Is this possible?

If that isn't possible, is it maybe possible to put *"ModItems."* and the item string ex. *"RUBY"* in a single string ex. *"ModItems.RUBY"* and run that string as code?

```
@Override
public Item getItemDropped(IBlockState state, Random rand, int fortune) {
     int a = ore_name.indexOf('_'); //ex. ore_name = ruby_ore
     String b = ore_name.substring(0,a); //ex. ruby
     String c = b.toUpperCase();//ex. RUBY
     return ModItems.b;//i want this to do ex. ModItems.RUBY
}
```

So if the ore_name is ex. *biotite_ore* the function should return **ModItems.BIOTITE**, for *pyroxine_ore* it should return **ModItems.PYROXINE**, etc.

Comment: So you want to basically parse string into variable names? I think a predefined Map might get your job done.

Comment: @Zigzagoon Haven't used Maps before, I'll try it out tomorrow (it's very late rn) but thank you!

Comment: If you can set ore_name to ruby_ore, why can't you simply set something like "itemToDrop" to ModItems.RUBY?

Comment: @kumesana  hey you just gave me a great idea: add an additional parameter to the OreBase class, the thing the ore drops! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 ways of doing this. Take your pick.

**1. Make `ModItems` an Enum containing an `Item` object:**

```java
     int a = ore_name.indexOf('_');
     String b = ore_name.substring(0,a);
     String c = b.toUpperCase();
     return ModItems.valueOf(c).getItem();
```

**Pros:** Simple, no need to update a map if a new item is added
**Cons:** Throws an exception if the `ModItem` doesn't exist
**2. Making a `Map<String, ModItem>` (preferred):**

```java
    return oreMap.get(ore_name);
```

**Pros:** Simple, easy to implement
**Cons:** You have to update your map every time you add an item and `get` returns null for unknown ores
**3. Reflection:**

```java
     int a = ore_name.indexOf('_');
     String b = ore_name.substring(0,a);
     String c = b.toUpperCase();
     return ModItems.class.getDeclaredField(c).get(null);
```

**Pros:** No need to update a map for every new item
**Cons:** Overkill, throws ugly checked exceptions, and is generally frowned upon unless absolutely necessary.